# How do I keep the part of a <div> that spills out of its parent container visible?

Tags: html, css, angular, overflow

I am creating a "console" for a card game that will hold the cards that are in your hand.  When a user selects a card, I want the card to move upward (as in, sit higher than the other cards).  The problem is that I want the selected card to appear above the console, but instead, the card is "cut off" once it leaves the bounds of the console (or specifically, the .hand-recess class).  How can I keep the card visible outside the bounds of its parent?

Here is a snippet of my HTML code:

```
<div class="hand-console-container">
    <div class="card-recess">
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card selected-card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.hand-console-container {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    bottom: 10px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: gray;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: green;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgb(0, 255, 0), 2px 2px 5px rgb(0, 255, 0) inset;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow-y: visible;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.card-recess {
    /* position: relative; */
    background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99);
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 4px 4px black;
    width: 95%;
    height: 90%;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 230px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px black;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: blue;
}

.selected-card {
    bottom: 100px;
}
```

Here is a link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ay2d75eg/

Comment: How is this: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/ynx9dkhe/

Answer (score 0):

Just set `overflow: visible` and your card will be visible outside the container.

```
.hand-console-container {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Unfortunately, `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` are not completely independent. Certain values of one will override certain values of the other. Here is a quote from [this spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) on the `overflow-x` property:

> If overflow-y is hidden, scroll, or auto, and the overflow-x property
> is visible (default), the value [of overflow-x] will be implicitly computed as auto.

And conversely from [the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y) on the `overflow-y` property:

> If overflow-x is hidden, scroll, or auto and the overflow-y property
> is visible (default), the value [of overflow-y] will be implicitly computed as auto.

Basically if you want `overflow: visible` to work, you can’t limit it to one direction only.

```css
.hand-console-container {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    height: 300px;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: gray;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: green;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgb(0, 255, 0), 2px 2px 5px rgb(0, 255, 0) inset;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}

.card-recess {
    /* position: relative; */
    background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99);
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 4px 4px black;
    width: 95%;
    height: 90%;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 230px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px black;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: blue;
}

.selected-card {
  bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hand-console-container">
    <div class="card-recess">
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card selected-card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh dang, that IS unfortunate!  Cause I definitely planned on having the cards be "scrollable" in the x axis if there were too many to fit in the recess.....so basically what I'm trying to do is impossible? :(   
I guess alternatively, I could just make the recess taller so that the card doesn't actually spill over....blahhhhh

Comment: Maybe when you select a card you’ll need to hide it in your scrolling container, but then create a copy of the card in another container which is outside the scrolling container but superimposed over it. If a card is selected, what should happen to it if the user then scrolls the cards horizontally?